# How to make ringtone.play() repeatable?

Tags: android, alarm, ringtone

I have a code which sets alarms for phone. I play the custom ringtone for user when the time comes. The issue is, ringtone.play() just plays once which is too short. I want to make it repeatable. In this way, user can hear that and can stop that. This is my code:

```
    String ringtoneUriString = StorageManager.loadAlarmRingtone(this)[1];
    Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(ringtoneUriString);
    ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
    ringtone.play();
```

Is anybody can help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can´t with a Ringtone...you have to use MediaPlayer for a looping alarm

Comment: Do you have any idea that how can I pass my ringtone to a MediaPlayer?

Comment: the same way you playing a song. See this tutorial:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm

Comment: It worked!! Thanks.